Are there graphs with multiple edge sets?
I've tried looking this up here and on google, but I think I may not be using the right words. I'm not talking about a mutligraph (multiple edges between the same nodes) or a hypergraph (multiple nodes involved in one edge). In a typical graph we have G(V, E) where V is the set of nodes and E is the set of edges.
Is there a way to have a graph G(V, E) where instead of E being a set of edges, it's a collection of sets of edges (directed or undirected)?
For example, let G describe an immediate family tree, with
V = {child, mother, father} and E as the collection of two sets, is_parent, a directed set of edges,  and married_to, an undirected set of edges, (where is_parent = {(mother, child), (father, child)} and married_to = {(mother, father)}).
It doesn't necessarily have to mix directedness (we could set the standard as directed and then have undirected edges simply be bidirectional). I know we could also just change this to be a weighted graph with each 'set' of edges representing a subset of edges that have a given weight (for example, setting all edges in is_parent to weight 1 and all in married_to to weight 2) but that doesn't seem right, as the edge types aren't more or less important than each other, just different.
Is this a thing in graph theory?

It's called a multigraph.

What you describe here is simply a collection of graphs over the same set of vertices.
